# Install Linux distro on a partition of my second drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I have my main Drive which is a SSD with Windows installed on it and a second Drive of 1 TB where I store some important files and data. I would like to create a partition on this second drive to install a Linux distro like Ubuntu. The problem is that I don't want to select the O.S. at boot, but keeping booting automatically to Windows. To boot to Linux I want to select a boot device at BIOS screen and then select my second drive. Is it possible? How can I do this in the set up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the boot loader for Linux on the second drive. It's common that you can specify that during the install.

To be really sure that you don't mess things up you could disable the SSD drive before you install the Linux distro.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm new in Linux world, but all that I try is: select manual partitioning, select the partition I made on the second drive of about 32 GB, I choose Automatically partition the free space and it makes an ext4 / partition and a swap partition, I proceed and at the and of the installation I choose to install the bootloader not in the master boot record but in the second drive. The probles is that any disk I choose, it will always boot to Windows

Comment: Even when you choose to boot from the second drive in BIOS? Have you tried to disable the SSD drive?

Comment: Exactly, just tried. Is it a partition problem?

Comment: I think it's needed that the second drive has the boot flag set, but I think that would be done by the installer of the bootloader. But it could be something to check at least. An UEFI BIOS could cause some issues here as well so I suggest you go through the BIOS options.